# Does the same variable allocate the same memory in different languages

Tags: python, memory-management, byte, allocation

I'm checking the bytes of `s=a` variable allocated in memory using Python.
The result is **50**

Will I get the same **50** bytes if I do the same in other languages?

My Python code is here

```
import sys
s ='a'

print(sys.getsizeof(s))
```

Comment: Maybe some, surely not all.

Comment: No, every language works differently. In C, a single character just takes 1 byte.

Comment: `sys.getsizeof(chr(127)) == 50, sys.getsizeof(chr(128)) == 74`

Comment: @Barmar I have already tried that and got it.
Now I'm reading a book (Data Structures and Algorithms in Python / Goodrich) and He says this.

As a tangible example, a text string is stored as an ordered sequence of
individual characters. In Python, each character is represented using the Unicode
character set, and on most computing systems, Python internally represents each
Unicode character with 16 bits (i.e., 2 bytes). Therefore, a six-character string, such
as SAMPLE , would be stored in 12 consecutive bytes of memory.

Why 2 bytes.  Can it be the differences of Python versions?

Comment: They're just talking about the character data, not the internal overhead that's used to manage the objects.

Comment: OK, Can I say that **"Internal Overhead" == 49** and every extra char +1 byte in Python?

Comment: @JoraKaryan That depends on the *implementation*, not the language itself.